# How to send an option from a drop-down menu to a separate submit button in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to send the option selected from a drop-down menu to a separate submit button. Here's my code so far:

```
 <tr>
         <td valign="top" style="width: 247px"><a href="action-amazon-sale.php?size=<?=$size?>&amp;id=<?=$product['product_id'];?>&barcode=<?=$barcode?>&shop_price=<?=$product['price']?>&brand=<?=$product['brand_id']?>&title=<?=$product['title']?>&colour=<?=$product['colour']?>&shoe_id=<?=$product['shoe_id'];?>">
          <input name="button5" type="submit" class="submit-button-green" id="button5" value="AMAZON SOLD" style="width:100%" onclick="this.disabled=1;"/>
          </a></td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
         <td>
            <form action="" style= "width: 250px" style="height: 38px; width: 350px">
            <select name="shipping" class="button_select" style="width: 345px">
            <option value="">SELECT SHIPPING FOR AMAZON &amp EBAY SALES</option>
            <option value="0">FREE UK SHIPPING</option>
            <option value="5.50">UK SHIPPING &pound; 5.50</option>
            <option value="6.95">BOOTS SHIPPING &pound; 6.95</option>
            <option value="14.95">EURO &pound; 14.95</option>
            <option value="19.95">EURO 2 &pound; 19.95</option>
            <option value="29.95">WORLD &pound; 29.95</option>
            </select>
            </form>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </table></td>
    </tr>
```

I want the user to first select a shipping option from the drop-down menu and upon clicking the 'AMAZON SOLD' submit button, have that value POST to the subsequent PHP page, i.e. action-amazon-sale.php ...

Can anybody please tell me how I should do this?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE #2

```
   <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 247px"><a href="action-amazon-sale.php?size=<?=$size?>&amp;id=<?=$product['product_id'];?>&barcode=<?=$barcode?>&shop_price=<?=$product['price']?>&brand=<?=$product['brand_id']?>&title=<?=$product['title']?>&colour=<?=$product['colour']?>&shoe_id=<?=$product['shoe_id'];?>">
          <input name="button5" type="submit" class="submit-button-green" id="button5" value="AMAZON SOLD" style="width:100%"  form="shipping" formmethod="post" 
  formaction="action-amazon-sale.php?size=<?=$size?>&amp;id=<?=$product['product_id'];?>&barcode=<?=$barcode?>&shop_price=<?=$product['price']?>&brand=<?=$product['brand_id']?>&title=<?=$product['title']?>&colour=<?=$product['colour']?>&shoe_id=<?=$product['shoe_id'];?>" onclick="this.disabled=1;"/>
          </a></td>  
          <td width="530" align="right"></td>
    </tr>
     <td width="252" valign="top" style="height: 13px"><a href="action-amazon-sale.php?size=<?=$size?>_con_b&amp;id=<?=$product['product_id'];?>&barcode=<?=$barcode?>&shop_price=<?=$product['price']?>&brand=<?=$product['brand_id']?>&title=<?=$product['title']?>&colour=<?=$product['colour']?>&shoe_id=<?=$product['shoe_id'];?>">
            <input name="button5" type="submit" class="submit-button-green" id="button5" value="AMAZON CONCESSION SOLD" style="width:100%"  form="shipping" formmethod="post" formaction="action-amazon-sale.php?size=<?=$size?>_con_b&amp;id=<?=$product['product_id'];?>&barcode=<?=$barcode?>&shop_price=<?=$product['price']?>&brand=<?=$product['brand_id']?>&title=<?=$product['title']?>&colour=<?=$product['colour']?>&shoe_id=<?=$product['shoe_id'];?>" onclick="this.disabled=1;"/>
            </a></td> 
          <tr>
                 <form id="shipping">
     <td valign="top">
              <select name="shipping" class="button_select" style="width: 276px">
              <option value="">SELECT SHIPPING FOR AMAZON SALES</option>
              <option value="0">FREE UK SHIPPING</option>
              <option value="16.95">EURO SHIPPING &pound; 16.95</option>
              <option value="14.50">BOOTS SHIPPING &euro; 17.50</option>
                  </select>       
             </form></td></tr>
      <tr>
```

On the target URL I have written a short test i.e.

```
$shipping=$_POST['shipping'];

echo $shipping;
```

However, the result is blank. Where am I going wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: Just put the select menu and the input button in the same form with an action pointing to "action-amazon-sale.php".

Comment: You will need to name your form. And use the `form=` attribute in the submit button. You can also add `formmethod` attribute to the submit button.

Comment: This seems like bad pratice. Why don't you have a single post handler that operates differently on the selected option value, rather than one post handler per option?

Comment: @iamsleepy Could you expand on your answer a litte? Perhaps flesh out an example? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the input button inside the form and `method` should be `POST`

```
<form method="POST" action="action-amazon-sale.php?size=<?= $size ?>&amp;id=<?= $product['product_id']; ?>&barcode=<?= $barcode ?>&shop_price=<?= $product['price'] ?>&brand=<?= $product['brand_id'] ?>&title=<?= $product['title'] ?>&colour=<?= $product['colour'] ?>&shoe_id=<?= $product['shoe_id']; ?>" style= "width: 250px" style="height: 38px; width: 350px"> 
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="width: 247px">
            <input name="button5" type="submit" class="submit-button-green" id="button5" value="AMAZON SOLD" style="width:100%" onclick="this.disabled = 1;"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select name="shipping" class="button_select" style="width: 345px">
              <option value="">SELECT SHIPPING FOR AMAZON &amp EBAY SALES</option>
              <option value="0">FREE UK SHIPPING</option>
              <option value="5.50">UK SHIPPING &pound; 5.50</option>
              <option value="6.95">BOOTS SHIPPING &pound; 6.95</option>
              <option value="14.95">EURO &pound; 14.95</option>
              <option value="19.95">EURO 2 &pound; 19.95</option>
              <option value="29.95">WORLD &pound; 29.95</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You id your form like this:

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="example" value="" />
</form>
```

And the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" form="myform" />
```

OR if you want to define the method, if you define the `formmethod` in your submit button it will override the `method` defined in the `<form>` tag.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" form="myform" formmethod="post" />
```

This indicate that the submit belongs to myform. I think this is HTML5 added attributes. Some browsers won't submit if the `submit` input is placed inside the form tags.

This attribute can be used for most if not all html `input`. This means you can have your input field placed outside the form but still belong to the form.

You can use your updated codes using separate form for each one. What you put in `a href` should be in the `formaction`.

```
<input type="submit" form="myform" formaction="action-amazon-sale.php?size=<?=$size?>&amp;id=<?=$product['product_id'];?>&barcode=<?=$barcode?>&shop_price=<?=$product['price']?>&brand=<?=$product['brand_id']?>&title=<?=$product['title']?>&colour=<?=$product['colour']?>&shoe_id=<?=$product['shoe_id'];?>"
```

Or you can just refer to one form. Like this:

```
        <form id="shipping" style= "width: 250px" style="height: 38px; width: 350px">
        <select name="shipping" class="button_select" style="width: 345px">
        <option value="">SELECT SHIPPING FOR AMAZON &amp EBAY SALES</option>
        <option value="0">FREE UK SHIPPING</option>
        <option value="5.50">UK SHIPPING &pound; 5.50</option>
        <option value="6.95">BOOTS SHIPPING &pound; 6.95</option>
        <option value="14.95">EURO &pound; 14.95</option>
        <option value="19.95">EURO 2 &pound; 19.95</option>
        <option value="29.95">WORLD &pound; 29.95</option>
        </select>
        </form>
```

with your buttons, like this:

```
  <input name="button5" type="submit" class="submit-button-green" id="button5" value="AMAZON SOLD" style="width:100%"  form="shipping" formmethod="post" 
  formaction="action-amazon-sale.php?size=<?=$size?>...." onclick="this.disabled=1;"/>

   <input name="button5" type="submit" class="submit-button-green" id="button5" value="AMAZON SOLD" style="width:100%"  form="shipping" formmethod="post" 
  formaction="action-amazon-sale.php?size=<?=$size?>_con_b&amp;id=" onclick="this.disabled=1;"/>
```

Comment: So could I use this approach for two separate buttons? Providing I tag each submit button with the 'myform' tag?

Comment: `myform` is the id of the form. You mean 2 buttons for the same form ? I think so.

Comment: Yes, so I wanted to send the option selected to either button depending on which button was clicked. So would I leave the value as "" (blank) within the form?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. Can you elaborate ? But, clicking either button will submit the same form. So, they would have the same input and values. I usually use two different buttons to send the request to two separate action. Eg.paypal or creditcard

Comment: You can define `formaction` for each submit button.

Comment: See my updates to my original post above - will my new code perform the post method to my submit button ?

Comment: Ahhh! Now I think I get it now. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Please see my updated question above - I'm still not receiving the value on the target url.